# How can i change thumbnail order?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please I am not familiar with **Bootstrap 3** and I started to build a small web journal using this framework. I found some difficulties and hope to get some solutions.

My question is how can I code ***3 thumbnails*** then change their order on mobile device?

```
<div class="col-lg-15 no-padding-left">
                            <div class="box-news">
                                <div class="block-title move no-margin">اقليم سيدي بنور</div>
                                <div class="news-items text-right">
                                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled no-margin thumb">
                                            <li class="thumbnail md">
                                                <div class="col-xs-8">
                                                    <a href="#" class="link-item">اعطاء انطلاقة الدخول التربوي لأقسام التربية غيرالنظامية بسيدي بنور</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-7 no-padding">
                                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://localhost/24/public/uploads/1444912297..jpg">
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="thumbnail md">
                                                <div class="col-xs-8">
                                                    <a href="#" class="link-item">استخدام سيارة للنقل المدرسي في سرقة أسمدة فلاحية من ضيعة برلماني بسيدي بنور</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-7 no-padding">
                                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://localhost/24/public/uploads/1444989659..jpg">
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="thumbnail lg">
                                            <img src="http://localhost/24/public/uploads/1445377322..jpg" alt="...">
                                            <div class="captison">
                                                <a href="#" class="link-item">جماعة سيدي بنور تساهم في المبادرة الملكية 'مليون محفظة'</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

The result that I want in the image below

[image]

Comment: Bootstrap uses a 12 column grid so unless you're using a custom build you'll need to adjust your columns accordingly and you should be using the row class in conjunction with your columns as well. See [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Comment: can you write the code for me me please to do that

Comment: you're looking for the classes `col-xs-12` and `col-sm-6` (or `md` or `lg`)

Comment: I'm looking for 12 xs please

Comment: `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><img /></div>` is what you're looking for for each image, though you haven't told us which images you want in which order on desktop.

Comment: no its incorrect, any way thank you

Comment: You may want to read the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) at some point, unless you're planning on asking the internet to write the whole application for you.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this will work: http://jsfiddle.net/WOUNDEDStevenJones/vf4h17L5/1/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">text1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">text2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">text3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you need them ordered differently, you can use the `-push-` and `-pull-` classes: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Comment: You can just copy/paste in your `<img src="..." />` where I have `text1`.  Are the images in the desktop view and the mobile view the same images? Or are you loading different images (with different resolutions and aspect ratios) depending on the device?

Comment: Answering `canihaztehcodez` questions just encourages them, and they very rarely provide any value to anyone but the question's creator.

Comment: They provided the code they had which wasn't working for them, and then asked for help. I don't think me providing said help along with the documentation in a comment is grounds for you disliking my answer...